# Dynamic finder methods for validation purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, constants

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to find some records at run time for validation purposes but passing\setting a value for that finder method. That is, in a my class I have the following:

```
class Group <  < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :relation_id,
    :presence  => true,
    :inclusion => {
      :in => ... # Read below for more information about
    }
end
```

If I set `:in` to be

```
:in => User.find(1).group_ids
```

it works, but I would like to set "some-dynamic-things" for the finder method instead of the `1` value stated below in the example. That is, I would like to do something like the following in order to pass to the model a `<test_value>` in someway:

```
class Group <  < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :relation_id,
    :presence  => true,
    :inclusion => {
      :in => User.find(<test_value>).group_ids
    }
end
```

Is it possible? If so, how can I pass the value to the constant?

P.S.: Just to know, I am trying to make that in order to move some logic from the controller to the model.

Comment: You should keep in mind the context in which that constant is evaluated.  It will be evaluated as Rails is loading all of its classes and models.  Is the value you want to pass in available at that point?  Also, dynamic constants are better known as methods or class variables.

Comment: @jaredonline - You are right. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inferring that what you're trying to do is enforce something like "Only users who are members of a group can save it."  If that's the case, you have behavior that should stay in the controller.

Your model doesn't have access to the current session, and adding this logic will prevent you from using your model for other things in the future.  For example, you'd never be able to save a group from a batch or maintenance job that wasn't associated with a user.

If you really want to do this you could put a `current_user` class level variable in the `User` object and set it in a `before_filter`...

```
class ApplicationController
  before_fitler :set_current_user
  def set_current_user
    User.current_user = #however you get your user in your controllers
  end
end

class User
  @@current_user
end

class Group
  validates :user_in_group
  def user_in_group
    return true unless User.current_user #if we don't have a user set, skip validation
    User.current_user.group_ids.include? self.id
  end
end
```

Comment: Glick - "Only users who are members of a group can save it." Exactly!!! - Even "your way" is another good way to solve the problem, is that a little too sophisticated?

Comment: BTW: If these behavior should stay in the controller I must repeat the related code in all involved action methods. It is not DRY approach.

Comment: Seems to me this is not a model validation problem(?), but a user interface or behaviour problem of the application. I.e. when a user tries to save a group, that user must belong to that group. Then it's a UI issue and I would not use validation for this. Validation is meant to verify the model being saved is in a valid state, it has nothing to do with WHO is doing the saving of the model. You have to rethink your problem..what is it exactly you want to do here?

Comment: This is turning into a long discussion, but I would perhaps instead add a method to Group called `save_by_user(user)` and you perform the check in there. Then in your UI (controllers), wherever this check is required you use this method to save the model with, and not the usual `save`. It makes much more sense this way, and much less "magic" in your application to decipher when you read it two months from now and wonder what the heck you wrote back then :)

Comment: @Casper - I have a check box field in a form for which users can select one or more of those values (that is, groups) and in order to save group relationships I use the "magic"\"automatic" Ruby on Rails "has_many collection_singular_ids" (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-collection_singular for more information).  I would like, as you said, "Only users who are members of a group can save it" and I would like to transfert this logic in to model validation methods. In case I use a `save_by_user(user)` method where I should insert this (controller, model, ...)?

Comment: I guess it depends how often you're saving groups.  If you're doing this all over the place, this might help with the DRY issue.  If it's not done too often, I'd trade the DRY for readability and leave it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like a proc to be run for the validator for the :in attribute. I think you may be threading in dangerous territory when you rely on load order of models and playing with "dynamic constants".

Instead how about just building your own custom validator for this case?
 It's not that hard, and you will have full control of what you need:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods

Comment: OK, you are right, but also using a custom validator I don't solve the problem of passing\setting the `<test_value>` at run time unless I add a new database table column (for example, named `user_id`) for the Group class\model and then, using the custom validator, I access that value by using a `self.user_id`: `User.find(self.user_id).group_ids`. However I think that I can not create a table column just for this purpose... it must be a better way to handle this issue.

Comment: I see. Ok..how about making a class variable for this purpose? Which you can then set from wherever you like. I.e. `Group.test_value = xyz`. And then in your custom validator you can do the `User.find(Group.test_value).group_ids`...perhaps that would work better?

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea, but it is hard to set that value because I am validating an associated model by using the RoR method `update_attributes` and `save`. Making that, probabily there is a strategy to accomplish what I would like to do, but I don't know that.